# How could I oversee remotely a Linux computer with my MacBook Pro using SSH?

Tags: linux, macos, ssh, linux-mint

I equipped Linux Mint on every computer that my coworkers have for all those times that I would like to jab them in the kisser, but I need to supervise their computers for when my boss yells and needs to understand how to get specific files in certain folders. I need to use OS X, but don't require a glossy GUI application. What's the best process to acquire access to those computers located in New York from California?

Answer (score 2):

Lets examine your option: ssh

It is convenient, easy to use, has a lot of capabilities besides remote shell access, is not using a GUI (but is capable of doing), is available on every ancient and modern OS and has been under a lot of scrutiny of security minded people since its inception.

Generally speaking, I refrain myself from using anything else than ssh for remote access.

If your clients dwell behind NAT firewalls (like a home router) you need to forward one TCP port for incoming connections, which may be a problem if your coworkers aren't tech savvy enough. Sometimes a forwarded port isn't enough to make a successful connection because some ISPs are herding their customers behind a second NAT, which neither you, nor your coworkers can configure. A solution to that problem would be to start a reverse shell connection from the coworkers host to your localhost, which you can use to traverse the NAT. This depends on a running sshd on the coworkers end and a second one on your machine. Should be very possible to install a sshd on nearly every machine nowadays.

You could add these `no-agent-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-pty` in front of a `pubkey-entry` in `.ssh/authorized_hosts`, to remove capabilities and feel more secure, while exposing ssh to the worlds best coworkers.

For convenience, I will show an example for using reverse ssh.
Essentially:

```
coworker@coworkershost $ ssh -R -f 30000:127.0.0.1:22 coworker@yourdomain.org -N
```

`30000` is the open port on your machines localhost, `22` the port where your sshd is listening and `coworker@yourdomain.org` is a valid login on your machine, where coworker can access. `-R` tells ssh to make a reverse connection. `-f` for forking the process into the background (optional) and `-N` for not running any command (e.g. login shell)

Then you should find a line like this, when issuing `netstat -tulpena` on your host.

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:30000         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1001       2575742286  -
```

From there you can easily login, if you have a valid login and an sshd running on the coworkers host.

```
you@yourdomain.org:~$ ssh -p 30000 you@localhost
You have new mail.
Last login: Tue May  3 15:32:42 2016 from nicolass-mbp.fritz.box
0 ✓ you@coworkershost ~ $
```

Here we are, having traversed 2 NAT and got a remote shell.

Next stop is how to write a proper SuperUser question. That includes narrowing down the topic to an answerable scope. Show the progress you have made so far, so one can understand your problem. Visit https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask for further knowledge.
I could go on, but stop here to give a very clear answer to your question:

I would advise to use just ssh.